# cannot convert undefined or null to object while writing unit test case

Tags: angular, unit-testing

While I try to run the unit test for the function, I am getting the error 'Cannot convert undefined or null to object'

Please guide where I am going wrong.

This is the function in the ts file-

```
filterTargetWeightingFactor(data: any) {
    const filterTargetWeight: any = [];
    Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
      filterTargetWeight.push(key);
    });
    return filterTargetWeight.sort();
  }
```

Below is the code in the spec file for the function-

```
it('should return sorted data', () => {
    const unsortedData = {
      'b':'abc',
      'c':'vgf',
      'a':'sdf'
    }
    let sortedData = [ ];
    Object.keys({'key': 'value'})
    let finalArr = component.filterTargetWeightingFactor(unsortedData);
    expect(finalArr).toBe(['a','b','c']);
  });
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error ?

Comment: Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {   for the  "Object.keys"